# How to get all Exit values from Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

`console.log(data);`

output:

```
{
  "Status": "OK",
  "Message": "",
  "Data": {
    "LocationId": 1,
    "LocationName": null,
    "LocationData": [

    ],
    "DeviceData": [

    ],
    "AverageData": [
      {
        "Timestamp": "2017-01-01T00:00:00",
        "Data": [
          {
            "Snapshot": false,
            "Id": null,
            "Timestamp": "2017-01-01T00:00:00",
            "Entry": 0,
            "Exit": 0,
            "Value": 0.0,
            "TimeType": "HOUR",
            "TimeTitle": "12 AM",
            "TimeTitleLong": "01 Jan 2017 12 AM",
            "Epoh": 1483228800000,
            "RecordCount": 0
          },
          {
            "Snapshot": false,
            "Id": null,
            "Timestamp": "2017-01-01T01     :00:00",
            "Entry": 0,
            "Exit": 0,
            "Value": 0.0,
            "TimeType": "HOUR",
            "TimeTitle": "01 AM",
            "TimeTitleLong": "01 Jan      2017 01 AM",
            "Epoh": 1483232400000,
            "RecordCount": 0
          },
          {
            "Snapshot": false,
            "Id": null,
            "Timestamp": "2017-01-01T02     :00:00",
            "Entry": 0,
            "Exit": 0,
            "Value": 0.0,
            "TimeType": "HOUR",
            "TimeTitle": "02 AM",
            "TimeTitleLong": "01 Jan      2017 02 AM",
            "Epoh": 1483236000000,
            "RecordCount": 0
          },
          {
            "Snapshot": false,
            "Id": null,
            "Timestamp": "2017-01-01T03     :00:00",
            "Entry": 0,
            "Exit": 0,
            "Value": 0.0,
            "TimeType": "HOUR",
            "TimeTitle": "03 AM",
            "TimeTitleLong": "01 Jan      2017 03 AM",
            "Epoh": 1483239600000,
            "RecordCount": 0
          },
          {
            "Snapshot": false,
            "Id": null,
            "Timestamp": "2017-01-01T04     :00:00",
            "Entry": 0,
            "Exit": 0,
            "Value": 0.0,
            "TimeType": "HOUR",
            "TimeTitle": "04 AM",
            "TimeTitleLong": "01 Jan      2017 04 AM",
            "Epoh": 1483243200000,
            "RecordCount": 0
          },
          {
            "Snapshot": false,
            "Id": null,
            "Timestamp": "2017-01-01T05     :00:00",
            "Entry": 0,
            "Exit": 0,
            "Value": 0.0,
            "TimeType": "HOUR",
            "TimeTitle": "05 AM",
            "TimeTitleLong": "01 Jan      2017 05 AM",
            "Epoh": 1483246800000,
            "RecordCount": 0
          }
        ],
        "Title": "13 Apr"
      }
    ],
    "WeekdaySummary": null,
    "WeekdayEmpty": null,
    "Locationcapacity": 500,
    "Total": 0.0,
    "Max": 0.0,
    "Min": 0.0,
    "Average": 0.0,
    "NonZeroAverageDataCount": 0,
    "PeakHours": {

    },
    "PeakHour1": "-",
    "PeakHour2": "-"
  }
}
```

now how to get all `Exit` values from this JSON object using JQuery or JavaScript ?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. Please show what you have tried and what research you have done

Comment: `$.each(data.Data.AverageData.Data, function (key,value){ console.log(key);}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to map over the array values and return the Exit status

```js
var data = {
  "Status": "OK",
  "Message": "",
  "Data": {
    "LocationId": 1,
    "LocationName": null,
    "LocationData": [

    ],
    "DeviceData": [

    ],
    "AverageData": [
      {
        "Timestamp": "2017-01-01T00:00:00",
        "Data": [
          {
            "Snapshot": false,
            "Id": null,
            "Timestamp": "2017-01-01T00:00:00",
            "Entry": 0,
            "Exit": 0,
            "Value": 0.0,
            "TimeType": "HOUR",
            "TimeTitle": "12 AM",
            "TimeTitleLong": "01 Jan 2017 12 AM",
            "Epoh": 1483228800000,
            "RecordCount": 0
          },
          {
            "Snapshot": false,
            "Id": null,
            "Timestamp": "2017-01-01T01     :00:00",
            "Entry": 0,
            "Exit": 0,
            "Value": 0.0,
            "TimeType": "HOUR",
            "TimeTitle": "01 AM",
            "TimeTitleLong": "01 Jan      2017 01 AM",
            "Epoh": 1483232400000,
            "RecordCount": 0
          },
          {
            "Snapshot": false,
            "Id": null,
            "Timestamp": "2017-01-01T02     :00:00",
            "Entry": 0,
            "Exit": 0,
            "Value": 0.0,
            "TimeType": "HOUR",
            "TimeTitle": "02 AM",
            "TimeTitleLong": "01 Jan      2017 02 AM",
            "Epoh": 1483236000000,
            "RecordCount": 0
          },
          {
            "Snapshot": false,
            "Id": null,
            "Timestamp": "2017-01-01T03     :00:00",
            "Entry": 0,
            "Exit": 0,
            "Value": 0.0,
            "TimeType": "HOUR",
            "TimeTitle": "03 AM",
            "TimeTitleLong": "01 Jan      2017 03 AM",
            "Epoh": 1483239600000,
            "RecordCount": 0
          },
          {
            "Snapshot": false,
            "Id": null,
            "Timestamp": "2017-01-01T04     :00:00",
            "Entry": 0,
            "Exit": 0,
            "Value": 0.0,
            "TimeType": "HOUR",
            "TimeTitle": "04 AM",
            "TimeTitleLong": "01 Jan      2017 04 AM",
            "Epoh": 1483243200000,
            "RecordCount": 0
          },
          {
            "Snapshot": false,
            "Id": null,
            "Timestamp": "2017-01-01T05     :00:00",
            "Entry": 0,
            "Exit": 0,
            "Value": 0.0,
            "TimeType": "HOUR",
            "TimeTitle": "05 AM",
            "TimeTitleLong": "01 Jan      2017 05 AM",
            "Epoh": 1483246800000,
            "RecordCount": 0
          }
        ],
        "Title": "13 Apr"
      },
      {
        "Timestamp": "2017-01-01T00:00:00",
        "Data": [
          {
            "Snapshot": false,
            "Id": null,
            "Timestamp": "2017-01-01T00:00:00",
            "Entry": 0,
            "Exit": 0,
            "Value": 0.0,
            "TimeType": "HOUR",
            "TimeTitle": "12 AM",
            "TimeTitleLong": "01 Jan 2017 12 AM",
            "Epoh": 1483228800000,
            "RecordCount": 0
          },
          {
            "Snapshot": false,
            "Id": null,
            "Timestamp": "2017-01-01T01     :00:00",
            "Entry": 0,
            "Exit": 0,
            "Value": 0.0,
            "TimeType": "HOUR",
            "TimeTitle": "01 AM",
            "TimeTitleLong": "01 Jan      2017 01 AM",
            "Epoh": 1483232400000,
            "RecordCount": 0
          },
          {
            "Snapshot": false,
            "Id": null,
            "Timestamp": "2017-01-01T02     :00:00",
            "Entry": 0,
            "Exit": 0,
            "Value": 0.0,
            "TimeType": "HOUR",
            "TimeTitle": "02 AM",
            "TimeTitleLong": "01 Jan      2017 02 AM",
            "Epoh": 1483236000000,
            "RecordCount": 0
          },
          {
            "Snapshot": false,
            "Id": null,
            "Timestamp": "2017-01-01T03     :00:00",
            "Entry": 0,
            "Exit": 0,
            "Value": 0.0,
            "TimeType": "HOUR",
            "TimeTitle": "03 AM",
            "TimeTitleLong": "01 Jan      2017 03 AM",
            "Epoh": 1483239600000,
            "RecordCount": 0
          },
          {
            "Snapshot": false,
            "Id": null,
            "Timestamp": "2017-01-01T04     :00:00",
            "Entry": 0,
            "Exit": 1,
            "Value": 0.0,
            "TimeType": "HOUR",
            "TimeTitle": "04 AM",
            "TimeTitleLong": "01 Jan      2017 04 AM",
            "Epoh": 1483243200000,
            "RecordCount": 0
          },
          {
            "Snapshot": false,
            "Id": null,
            "Timestamp": "2017-01-01T05     :00:00",
            "Entry": 0,
            "Exit": 1,
            "Value": 0.0,
            "TimeType": "HOUR",
            "TimeTitle": "05 AM",
            "TimeTitleLong": "01 Jan      2017 05 AM",
            "Epoh": 1483246800000,
            "RecordCount": 0
          }
        ],
        "Title": "14 Apr"
      }
    ],
    "WeekdaySummary": null,
    "WeekdayEmpty": null,
    "Locationcapacity": 500,
    "Total": 0.0,
    "Max": 0.0,
    "Min": 0.0,
    "Average": 0.0,
    "NonZeroAverageDataCount": 0,
    "PeakHours": {

    },
    "PeakHour1": "-",
    "PeakHour2": "-"
  }
}

var arr = [];

arr = data.Data.AverageData.map(function(data) {

  return data.Data.map(function(item) {
      
  return item.Exit;
  })
})
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: it return the first data array fine, but it didn't continue to iterate through other `Data` array..  because the file is large so I just show the first `Data` array

Comment: So you have multiple averageData objects and do you want the exit status in a single array or array of arrays

Comment: in the question I just include for one day data, so `2017-01-01T00:00:00"` return data of first January only. Now lets say the second day of January has data as well, so it will give a new array of data in `2017-01-02T00:00:00` something like this `{"Timestamp":"2017-01-02T00:00:00","Data":[{"Snapshot":false,"Id":null,"Timestamp":"2017-01-02T00:00:00","Entry":0,"Exit":0,"Value":0.0,"TimeType":"HOUR","TimeTitle":"12 AM","TimeTitleLong":"02 Jan 2017 12 AM","Epoh":1483315200000,"RecordCount":0}`

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that `Exit` only exists exactly as you've indicated in this example, you could do the following:

```
const dataObject = JSON.parse(data);
dataObject.Data.AverageData.Data.forEach(datum => {
    console.log(datum.Exit);
});
```